# Django conditional details in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

In my Django application there are users with `department codes` and I want show different details on template to these users, but superusers should see everything. Here are my codes:

`template.html`:

```
{% if user.is_superuser or user.department_code=1%}
<p>Your department code is 1 or you are a superuser</p>
{% elif user.is_superuser or user.department_code=2%}
<p>Your department code is 2 or you are a superuser</p>
{% else %}
<p> You are a superuser</p>
{% endif %}
```

In this case I am as a superuser seeing only first paragraph. How could I do it correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by your usage of `{% elif %}`.

If you are a superuser then the first condition is checked, which evaluates `True`, and then your following `{% elif %}`s and `{% else %}` aren't checked anymore. Your second `{% elif %}` is only considered if the first condition is `False`, which is why it works if you are not a superuser. For your `{% else %}` to trigger the first two conditions must both be `False`. This could happen for example if you are logged in as a non-superuser and the department code is 3.

Simply replace your `{% elif %}`s with `{% if %}` and it will work.

```
{% if user.is_superuser or user.department_code == 1 %}
    <p>Your department code is 1 or you are a superuser</p>
{% endif %}
{% if user.is_superuser or user.department_code == 2 %}
    <p>Your department code is 2 or you are a superuser</p>
{% endif %}
{% if user.is_superuser %}
    <p> You are a superuser</p>
{% endif %}
```

You were also missing "="s in your equality checks, note how I use two in each condition instead of only one.